# MSGPACK-RPC (C++) under windows

Tags: c++, msgpack

Did anyone managed to put msgpack-rpc (C++) to work under windows, through cygwin or mingw?

Thanks,
SwatchPuppy

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented msgpack-rpc sometimes ago: https://github.com/qehgt/myrpc It uses `boost` library and was used in Linux/Windows environment in production.